# Windows 7 not booting, could not restore boot record

Tags: windows, multi-boot, mbr

After not using Windows 7 for a month (and a few Ubuntu 11.10 updates being applied), I found I'm no longer able to boot from GRUB2 to Windows.

I've tried to reinstall GRUB2, and have done some other things (installed GAG for example). As a last resort I've booted with the Windows 7 rescue disk and tried the following command:

```
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

However it found no partition with Windows. GRUB does detect it, but just shows a blank screen after selecting it.

Any ideas how to fix this? Perhaps a few extra commands that need to be entered in the GRUB2 Windows' option?